# Is there a way to execute code in the parent process after the child, which is created using fork and execl?

Tags: c, process, signals, fork, exec

I am having a parent process `play` that creates a fork and runs `foo` using `execl`

Code for `play.c`

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    if (fork() == 0) {
      execl("./foo", "", NULL);
    } else {
      wait(0);
      write(STDOUT_FILENO, "in parent after waiting", 5);
    }
  printf("outside everything");
  return 0;
}
```

Code for `foo.c`

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signal_handler() {
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\nBye!\n", 6);
  exit(1);
}

int main() {
  struct sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

  while (1) {
    printf("Wasting time...%d \n", getpid());
    sleep(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My questions are,

- Why aren't the print statements after the `wait(0)` statement executed?
- Why isn't the signal handler in the child process triggered when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: The parent doesn't have a `SIGINT` handler, so it's killed by Ctl-C.

Comment: Does `execl` succeed? What is the output? What does `wait(0)` return? Etc, basic debugging details...

Comment: You should ensure that the `sa_flags` and `sa_mask` fields of `struct sigaction` are set.  You can initialize them — `struct sigaction sa = { 0 };` will probably do the job.  Or you can use `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);` and `sa.sa_flags = 0;` to assign values.  Or you can set them to some non-zero value.  Not setting `sa_flags` means you've no idea what operation you requested.  You also need a signal handler in `play.c`.  Probably, you need to ignore `SIGINT` before the `fork()`, then in the child re-enable the signal before executing `foo`.  The `write()` in the parent does not print much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ensure that the `sa_flags` and `sa_mask` fields of `struct sigaction` are set.  You can initialize them — `struct sigaction sa = { 0 };` will probably do the job.  Or you can use `sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);` and `sa.sa_flags = 0;` to assign values.  Or you can set them to some non-zero value.  Not setting `sa_flags` means you've no idea what operation you requested.  You also need a signal handler in `play.c`.  You need to ignore `SIGINT` before the `fork()`, then in the child re-enable the signal before executing `foo`.  The `write()` in the parent does not print much; it may once have printed `"\nBar!\n"` or something.

Here's some working code.

#### `play.c`

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa = { 0 };
    sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        sa.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;
        sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
        execl("./foo", "", NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(0);
        printf("in parent after waiting\n");
    }
    printf("outside everything\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### `foo.c`

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    char message[] = "\nBye (XX)\n";
    message[6] = signum / 10 + '0';
    message[7] = signum % 10 + '0';
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, sizeof(message) - 1);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction sa = { 0 };
    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Wasting time...%d \n", getpid());
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

```
$ play
Wasting time...11383 
Wasting time...11383 
Wasting time...11383 
Wasting time...11383 
^C
Bye (02)
in parent after waiting
outside everything
$
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why it's important to initialise `sa_flags`? Also, changing the behaviour of the signal handler to default inside the child doesn't seem to have an effect on the way the process executes. Is it because the `execl` call replaces the process with the one we are executing? Because then the process that replaced can use its own signal handler.

Comment: There are a number of flag values that can be set in `sa_flag` — they're listed in the POSIX specification for [`sigaction()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) — and specific platforms may have extra options.  If the bit for `SA_SIGINFO` is set, your signal handler will be called with extra arguments, for example.  You may also change how dead child processes are handled, and so on.  If you don't initialize `sa_flags`, it is hit'n'miss about which ones are actually set.  It is generally a good idea to ensure that structures are fully initialized.

Comment: The classic way of setting signal handlers with the [`signal()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) function is to first set the signal handler to `SIG_IGN`, and the only install the handler if the old handler (which is returned by `signal()`) is not `SIG_IGN`. Your child installs its interrupt handler unconditionally, so it is hard to spot the change. The parent needs to ignore interrupt before it forks so that it won't be interrupted too soon. If it waits until after the fork, it might be interrupted before it gets to run again — unlikely, but possible.